# Error while creating ASP.net database register connection

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to make this following error: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

```
    protected void Button_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from [Table] where Användarnamn='" + TextBoxAnvändarelogin.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from Table where Användarnamn='" + TextBoxAnvändarelogin.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
            string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" " , ""); // ERROR HERE!
            conn.Close();
            if (password==TextBoxLösenordlogin.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = TextBoxAnvändarelogin.Text;
                Response.Write("Lösenord är rätt!");
                Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Lösenord är fel!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Användarnamn är inte rätt!");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from Table where Användarnamn`
should be
 `string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from [Table] where Användarnamn`

Side note: it is never a good practice to use string append to build dynamic sql. See Sql Injection for details. And shouldn't use "Table" as a Table name

Comment: Okay so i tried this but now a new problem appeared :An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid column name 'password'.

Comment: @Wharruphomie do you have a column named password in your table? Note its case sensitive

Comment: aaaaaa alright i changed it to the columname as i have in my table and it works Thanks bro :)

Comment: @Wharruphomie, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark under voting button instead of saying Thanks, to show your appreciation.